# DarkGDK changing display mode makes sprites dissapear

Tags: c++, wizard, gdk

After executing the application, user clicks the start button. At the time I want to change the display to different dimensions. But doing that the screen becomes black and images doesn't paste.

```
while ( LoopGDK ( ) )
    {

        if(dbMouseClick()==1){
            int x=dbMouseX(), y=dbMouseY();

            if(x>370 && x<498 && y>240 && y<368){
                dbDeleteImage(1);
                dbDeleteImage(2);
                bg_exist=false;
            }
        }
        if(!dbSpriteExist(1)&&bg_exist==false){
            dbSetDisplayMode(800,224,32);
            dbPasteImage(3,0,0);
        }

        dbSprite(2,370,240,2);
        dbPasteImage(1,0,0);
        dbSync ( );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This engine is outdated and almost not used by any one anymore.

There are plenty way better engines out there, full list can be found [**here**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines)

My favourite would be [**unreal engine**](http://www.unrealengine.com/)

I would suggest to play around with unreal engine since it has way better support and more easy to use features.

Comment: You're probably right. I should look around more accurately before choosing next time.